# Error while install hadoop on mac

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, installation, mapreduce

I was trying to install hadoob on mac. I got the following error. What could be the issue?

> hadoop-0.20.203.0 administrator$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: hadoop-*-examples.jar

```
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:90)
```

Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

```
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:88)
```

-Anish-

Comment: That's not installing hadoop; you can't specify a wildcard trying to run a jar.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with an example from the book Hadoop In Action.  It turns out either the book had it wrong or the example jars now have a different naming scheme.  In any case, your command should now begin with:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar
```